# Step by step guide for using JNDI in Tomcat for Oracle

Tags: tomcat, jndi

I have an existing spring framework based web application. I want to use JNDI on Tomcat 6 and Oracle server for it. Please explain a simple step by step procedure for the same.

Comment: +1 for your question.However,an application server like JBoss and WAS gives you many custmized features such as DB  connection pooling will really make your application perform well for heavy load applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Add the following code in the tag `<GlobalNamingResources>` in the following file:

> apache-tomcat-6.0.37/conf/server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbName" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   username="xyz" password="abcd"
                   url="jdbc:url"
                   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                   initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
                   maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"                   
                poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
```

---

2. Add the following code in the tag `<Context>` in the following file

> apache-tomcat-6.0.37/conf/context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/dbName" global="jdbc/dbName" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

---

3. Add the following code in the file

> applicationContext.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/dbName" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

---

4. Make sure the `<beans:xmlns` tag in the `applicationContext.xml` has the following data:

> xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

and these schemas in their `xsi:schemaLocation` :

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
```

---

5. Ensure that

> ojdbc14.jar

is present in the folder:

> apache-tomcat-6.0.37\lib

---

6. Remove the previous database connection parameters defined in your application(property files/dataSource beans defined in applicationContext.xml).

That should be enough.

Comment: Where is this applicationContext.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

This was a great knowledge,
Can you please also share how to condigure JNDI for external LDAP datasource?

The database JNDI worked finne for me after following your steps.
You can get more details in below link.
[External LDAP JNDI connectivity using Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249394/external-ldap-jndi-connectivity-using-tomcat)

Thanks
Anny

Comment: sorry i have no idea about LDAP configuration. I will try to find out though.