# External LDAP JNDI connectivity using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ldap, jndi

I wanted to Know how external LDAP is connected using JNDI configuration in TOMCAT.

My code is something like

```
try {
    InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext();
    ctx = (LdapContext) iniCtx.lookup("external/ldap/worker");
    //System.out.println("LDAP Context initialized::"+ctx);
    if(ctx!=null) {
        urlProvider=ctx.getEnvironment().get("java.naming.provider.url").toString();
    } 

} catch (NamingException ne) {                        
    throw new NamingException(ne.toString());
}
```

My Context.xml in Tomcat has following entry

```
<Resource 
  useDataSourceFactory="true"
  name="external/ldap/worker"
  auth="Container"
  type="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
  java.naming.factory.initial="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
  java.naming.provider.url="ldap://corpt605.corporate.***.***:13891"
  java.naming.security.authentication="simple"
  java.naming.security.principal="uid=cpasysuser,ou=******,o=***.com"
  java.naming.security.credentials="*********"
/>
```

And my web.xml has following entry

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>E2k Ldap Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>external/ldap/worker</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

When I use this JNDI datasource I get following error:

> 08 Oct 2014 10:12:03,394 ERROR waveset.ge.commons.LdapJndiConnection_CDI:52 - getLdapCntxt::Error occured during Ldap context lookupjavax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [external/ldap/worker] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [external].

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to configure LDAP as JNDI Resource in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040980/trying-to-configure-ldap-as-jndi-resource-in-tomcat)

Comment: Hi, I read that blog before, but that is for and ldap within same jvm. I am using ldap on diff jvm. So that may not help in my case. The tomcat is not accepting the resource name and hence not giving me context of ldap jndi.

Comment: It isn't a blog, it's an SO question, and it isn't 'for an LDAP within the same JVM'. There is no such thing.